# How can I read default values of any view?

Tags: android

Can I read default values of any view for example I want to read default button, toolbar or textview attributes etc...

I want it manually not programmatically

Comment: can you be more clear what you are asking for , if you want to see default attributes of a view switch to the *design* view of your xml file and open the attributes tab near the top right edge of the edge of the screen. And then select the view whose attributes you want to see either from the design or the component tree.

Comment: @Gaurav can I find the attributes on file instead of UI?

Comment: what do you mean by attributes on a file , if you want to see the code and the attributes at the same time just open the **Switch** view

Comment: I was mean when I add button there will be default values such as textAllCaps="true" and default background, Where can I find these values?

Comment: you can find all these values in the attribute pane , open the xml file and there you will see 3 buttons on top right corner , Code , Split , Design . The attribute button will appear on when you are in Split or Design view , then click on the attribute button to see the complete list of attributes but to see the attributes of your button click on the button inside the design or blueprint of your design

Comment: @Gaurav These default attributes it must be in specific file, What is name that file?

Comment: There is no default attribute file . there are very few attributes applied on the view when it is created like text value , color , size , font and the visibility , they are just applied and can be seen in attributes pane , there is no file.